# How to display a table in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do I print this table?
I'm using the corona simulator and the print() function doesn't output anything. What should I do?

```
local t = {}
 t.number = 10
 t.string = "Hello World"
 t.bool = true
 t.table = { someOtherString = "random", someOtherNumber = 5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `for-loop` to print items from table:

for example:

```
for key, value in ipairs(t) do
  print(key, value)
end
```

you can also use `print_r` function from @ldurniat post or [inspect](https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua) library (useful to print nested tables)

Comment: Why can't I see anything on the corona simulator, nothing is displaying?

Comment: can you paste full example? if you do that then maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [print_r](https://github.com/robmiracle/print_r) function (Lua based table printing funciton similar to the PHP print_r function) from Rob Miracle.